# Unable to Use IsLike operator on first table in nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

```
public IEnumerable<Mp_ProviderProfile> Find(string customerName = null
       , string  emailId = null, string providercode = null, string providercity = null)
{
    var query = Session.QueryOver<Mp_ProviderProfile>()
                       .JoinQueryOver<User>(x => x.AccountInfo);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerName))
            query = query.And(x => x.UserName.IsLike("%" + customerName + "%"));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailId))
            query = query.And(x => x.EmailId.IsLike("%" + emailId + "%"));



    return query.List();

}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderCode))
    MpProviderProfiles = MpProviderProfiles
         .Where(x => x.ProviderCode.IsLike("%" + ProviderCode + "%"));
```

Unable to get property of `Mp_ProviderProfile` in where condition in query

First two query of method Find is working fine but I am not able to apply is IsLike  operator on this  query

```
MpProviderProfiles = MpProviderProfiles
    .Where(x => x.ProviderCode.IsLike("%" + ProviderCode + "%"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to split `QueryOver` definition into 2 pieces:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Mp_ProviderProfile>();
var userQuery = query.JoinQueryOver<User>(x => x.AccountInfo);
```

Now, we do have access to both parts and we can query their *tables* like this

```
//  Mp_ProviderProfile
query.Where(x => x.ProviderCode.IsLike("%" + ProviderCode + "%"));

// User
userQuery.And(x => x.UserName.IsLike("%" + customerName + "%"));
```

*NOTE: the assignment `query = query.And(...` is not needed. These methods (`Where()`, `And()`) will add the Restriction into inner collection*

Comment: But As In my method I am returning query object .How can i return 2 object at same time

Comment: Well in your method you are not returning query! That is very improtant. you call `List()` and that means immediate execution of the query. If you want to work with the query, you should split it as in my answer, and return the top `query`. You can later add more restrictions and finally call `List()`. Does it make sense?

Comment: You have created 2 objects.But How can I do by creating one object .And I need List of Mp_ProviderProfile at last

Comment: I created the same amount of objects as you. But all the time I keep reference to the first query, resulting from `QueryOver<Mp_ProviderProfile>();` while you do not have that reference. My approach only keeps both queries in different variables. What you will return and where you will call `List()` is up to you. But if you do return `List()` you cannot apply more restrictions, because query was already executed

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(providercity))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Location.City.IsLike("%" + providercity + "%"));    How can i query over Location table with same
            }

Comment: Yeap, that seems to be the right way. `QueryOver` could be a bit more difficult to get in, but the benefits later ;)